# Printing all strings in a Ghidra project with python

Tags: ghidra, python

I got the string objects from a Ghidra project using this code:

```
 l = list()
def callback(s):
   l.append(s)
ss = StringSearcher(currentProgram, 5, 1, False, True)
ss.search(None, callback, True, monitor)

print(l[0])
```

got it from the thread [How to use findStrings flat API (#1964)](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/1964).

The problem is that in order to get the actual string, a Memory object is needed as a param of the `getString()` function.

I'm not really sure how to create this object or what it exactly represents… any right way/good example for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it apparently `currentProgram` has a get attribute that returns said Memory (MemoryMapDB):
`StringObj.getString(currentProgram.getMemory())`